# Open Outlook links in Chrome

Tags: samsung, chrome-for-android, browser, outlook

Using Outlook version 4.2041.3 on my Samsung Galaxy A30s with Android 10.

If I receive an email with links in it

[image]

And then click in the link

[image]

it opens up in a weird browser.

I would like for it to open in Chrome instead. How can that be done?

Already [contacted support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-in-app-help-for-outlook-for-ios-and-android-218a22d1-9fa5-4889-b689-de1c63493243#ID0EAABAAA=Contact_Support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Support

> This is a new Edge webview experience with the Bing search
> capabilities which is expected. **There is no way to disable this at the moment**. However, if you want to open a link in the default browser,
> you will need to click the link, then tap on the overflow menu at the
> bottom and choose "Open in Browser".